# Extracting data in a record from XML in SQL Server column

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have a column with xml data type like this:

```
       <Test ID="rs232lon">
        <Param Name="corel" Value="0.00000" />
        <Param Name="co2rel" Value="10.8000" />
        <Param Name="hcrel" Value="111.000" />
        <Param Name="o2rel" Value="0.95000" />
      </Test>
```

How could I get a result with TSQL like this :

```
corel       co2rel        hcrel        o2rel    
------------------------------------------          
0.00000     10.8000       111.000     0.95000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @CocoJambo TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    XmlColumn XML NOT NULL
);

INSERT  @CocoJambo (XmlColumn)
VALUES  (N'<Test ID="rs232lon">
    <Param Name="corel" Value="0.00000" />
    <Param Name="co2rel" Value="10.8000" />
    <Param Name="hcrel" Value="111.000" />
    <Param Name="o2rel" Value="0.95000" />
  </Test>');

SELECT  a.*,
        b.c.value('(Param[@Name="corel"]/@Value)[1]','NUMERIC(38,5)') AS corel,
        b.c.value('(Param[@Name="co2rel"]/@Value)[1]','NUMERIC(38,5)') AS co2rel,
        b.c.value('(Param[@Name="hcrel"]/@Value)[1]','NUMERIC(38,5)') AS hcrel,
        b.c.value('(Param[@Name="o2rel"]/@Value)[1]','NUMERIC(38,5)') AS o2rel
FROM    @CocoJambo a
CROSS APPLY a.XmlColumn.nodes('/Test') AS b(c)
```

Results:

```
ID XmlColumn                corel   co2rel   hcrel     o2rel
-- ------------------------ ------- -------- --------- -------
1  <Test ID="rs232lon">...  0.00000 10.80000 111.00000 0.95000
```

Comment: Also: Replace the precision (38) and scale (5) for `NUMERIC` data type.

Comment: i have several Test tag that Are distinct by ID , how could i do this in other Test tags

Comment: @SaraAlizadeh: You changed the question. You should cancel this change and accept the answer (because it gives the requested results - initial question). Then you could write another question and somebody will give you an answer. Anyway, if you look at my answer and if you read documentation you may find yourself an answer for the second question.